# How do i allow/deny a key based on how many times it appears on a listbox?

Tags: textbox, listbox, key, keypress, keydown

So i got a listbox where i'll have random vowels/cons and i wanna limit what the person can write on the textbox according to these keys i'll have on the listbox. So far i got to allowing only whats on the listbox but you can use it as many times as you want (ex you have ABIIDC on the listbox, you can type aaaaaaabbbbbiiiiiidddddddccc on the texbox), and what i want is for them to be able to use each key the times it apperas on the listbox (in the previous case, a once, b once, i twice, d once, c once).
This is what i have so far:

```
 private bool denykey = false;
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        denykey = false;
        if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(e.KeyCode))
        {
            denykey = true;
        }
          }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
     if (denykey == true)
     {
         e.Handled = true;
       }
       if(Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
       {
           e.Handled = true;
       }
    }
```

don't mind the "control" part, it's only to prevent copy and paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with help from some friends i was able to get what i wanted, here is what we did:

```
  private bool denykey = false;
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back) 
        { 
            denykey = false;
        return;
        }

        var countText = 0;
        foreach (var letter in textBox1.Text)
            if (letter.Equals(e.KeyCode.ToString()[0]))
                countText = countText + 1;

        var countList = 0;
        foreach (var letterList in listBox1.Items)
            if (letterList.ToString().Equals(e.KeyCode.ToString()))
                countList = countList + 1;

        denykey = false;

      if (countText >= countList)
            denykey = true;





    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
     if (denykey == true)
     {
         e.Handled = true;
       }
       if(Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
                     e.Handled = true;

    }
```